Holding time during static structural testing of a composite wing
While doing a static structural testing of a composite wing (high aspect ratio or otherwise), is there an industry practice or standard that determines the holding time for which a load is applied through whiffle tree. Specially, when we reach the DLL or DUL. Would keeping the wing deflected at DLL or DUL for longer duration that is few minutes make any difference?

The testing of composite wings I witnessed held the highest load for three seconds in order to pass the test. If you put high loads on a composite structure for the first time, you will get some minor cracking as the local peak loads get "re-routed". This process takes only a very short time, so three seconds were considered enough for this re-routing to finish.

Probably not. It's pretty much implied by the word "static" that this is an all or nothing proposition.  Either the structure will fail more or less immediately upon reaching the maximum load, or its good for a long period of time.  1 minute versus 1 hour will not make any difference.  Now, if you were to hold the load for a VERY long time (say a few years) then the polymers in the matrix would eventually creep.  But that's not really a relevant load case for a wing structure.
